# Environment variable to point to workspace

Tags: environment-variables, workspace, ibm-rad

Is there any environment variable defined in IBM RAD/WAS which points to the current workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly your answer, do you mean in the OS Environment Variables, like PATH? There is no such thing.

If, however, you want to use a variable within RAD that points to your current workspace for the purposes of running an application and you want to resolve a JAR, you can use the variable ${eclipse_home}.

Again, more information about the purpose of such variable will be helpful

Comment: I believe the question is, "If I launch WAS using RAD, is there a way to detect the RAD workspace from within code running in WAS?"  I believe the answer is "No", or at least not trivially or by default.